# Using Gradle to Build an IntelliJ Module From Command Line

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line, gradle

I understand the basic functionality of gradle, but I don't understand how to use a build.gradle file other than the one in the project's root. I have a project which contains a gradle wrapper in it's root, and a module which has it's own build.gradle file. How do I specify for gradlew to use the module's build.gradle file instead of the one in the root directory?

Specifically, I have an IntelliJ project I have uploaded to my CI server, and I am trying to setup a script to run the builds automatically.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a multi-module build which only has a single module... correct?

1. You could include a [settings.gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/multiproject/settings.gradle) which points to the module
2. You could declare a [GradleBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_build) task in the root module to invoke the sub module.

A good place to look for inspiration is the [java samples](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java) and the [organizing build logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) page in the documentation. An impressive feature of gradle is that all of the code snippets which appear in the documentation is sourced from the [samples](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples) directory which is run as part of their [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) build.

Happy Gradling!